# How to monitor array's and reset when limit is reached. VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist

I have a VB.Net program that loops through array's to try to figure out where bottles are on a "conveyor". The point of this program is to visually show staff, how the conveyor works using VB.net and Labels. It's extremely difficult to explain, so I’ll do my best.

Bottle_Number(10) Bottle_Position(128)

There are 10 bottles that I want to track at all 128 stops on the conveyor.

We have a conveyor that can only fit 10 bottles.  I need to track the position of each of the 10 bottles.  Once bottle 11 comes on - That means bottle 1 is completed and off the conveyor.  So, bottle 11 becomes bottle 1, so I need to reset the position of bottle1 to 0, and continue tracking bottles 2-9 while also tracking bottle 11(Not bottle 1).  Once bottle 12 comes on it becomes bottle 2, and I need to reset the position of bottle 2 to '0' and continue tracking all bottles.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class frmMain
Dim Product_Position(10) As Integer
Dim Inches_Per_Pulse As Integer
Dim PulseNumber As Integer
Dim Product_Counter As Integer
Dim Product_Location(10) As Integer
Dim Function1 As Integer
Dim Function2 As Integer
Dim Function3 As Integer
Dim Function4 As Integer
Dim Function5 As Integer
Dim Function6 As Integer
Dim Function7 As Integer
Dim Function8 As Integer
Dim Function9 As Integer
Dim Function10 As Integer
Dim Product_in_Tunel As Integer
Dim test As Integer
Dim Roll_OVer As Boolean
Dim Product_Counter_Test As Integer


Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    lblStatus.BackColor = Color.Green
    lblStatus.Text = "Conveyor Status: Running"
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    lblStatus.BackColor = Color.Red
    lblStatus.Text = "Conveyor Status: Off"

End Sub
Private replace_next As Integer
Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click

    If Product_Counter = 10 Then
        replace_next += 1
        If replace_next > 10 Then


            replace_next = 1 ' replace them in turn 1..10, then loop back to 1
            Product_Position(replace_next) = 0 ' put initial position here

        End If
    End If
    Product_Counter = Product_Counter + 1

    If Product_Counter > 10 Then
        Product_Counter = 1
        Roll_over = True
    End If

    'MsgBox(Product_Counter)
    'MsgBox(replace_next)

End Sub



Private Sub btnPulse_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPulse.Click

    Get_Location()





End Sub


Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PulseNumber = "0"
    Inches_Per_Pulse = "1"
    Roll_OVer = False
    'MsgBox("Test")
End Sub


Public Sub Get_Location()
    'MsgBox(Product_Counter)
    If Roll_OVer = True Then
        Product_Counter_Test = 10

        'MsgBox("i'm stuck here")
    End If


    If Roll_OVer = False Then
        Product_Counter_Test = Product_Counter
    End If
    'MsgBox(Product_Counter_Test)
    'MsgBox("am I here - Yes")
    For test = 1 To Product_Counter_Test

        'MsgBox("This works")
        Product_Position(test) = Product_Position(test) + Inches_Per_Pulse

    Next

    PulseNumber = PulseNumber + 1
    ClearLabels()
    lblProduct1Position.Text = Product_Position(1)
    lblProduct2Position.Text = Product_Position(2)
    lblProduct3Position.Text = Product_Position(3)
    lblProduct4Position.Text = Product_Position(4)
    lblProduct5Position.Text = Product_Position(5)
    lblProduct6Position.Text = Product_Position(6)
    lblProduct7Position.Text = Product_Position(7)
    lblProduct8Position.Text = Product_Position(8)
    lblProduct9Position.Text = Product_Position(9)
    lblProduct10Position.Text = Product_Position(10)
End Sub


Public Sub ClearLabels()

    lblProduct1Position.Text = ""
    lblProduct2Position.Text = ""
    lblProduct3Position.Text = ""
    lblProduct4Position.Text = ""
    lblProduct5Position.Text = ""
    lblProduct6Position.Text = ""
    lblProduct7Position.Text = ""
    lblProduct8Position.Text = ""
    lblProduct9Position.Text = ""
    lblProduct10Position.Text = ""


End Sub
```

[image: Screen Shot of Form]

The Pulse button is what is actually driving the conveyor, each pulse (click of the button) means the conveyor is  moving forward.

Right now once the program gets to bottle 11, it resets and only moves forward the "new" bottle (bottle1).  It should continue incrementing the remaining bottles until they reach the end and do the same for them - Reset the position to 0 and begin counting again.

Comment: A `Queue(of T)`, `LinkedList(of T)` or even a `List(Of T)` could act as the FIFO container.  A small class wrapper could implement the logic for strict size limiting.  You should turn on Option Strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, once you have 11 bottles, you don't want to reset to only one bottle, but instead still have 10 bottles, and replace one of them.  You'll need a second variable to keep track of which is to be replaced.
So instead of :

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    Product_Counter = Product_Counter + 1
    If Product_Counter > 10 Then Product_Counter = 1
End Sub
```

It would be something like:

```
Private Replace_Next as Integer = 0

Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    If Product_Counter = 10 Then
        Replace_Next += 1
        If Replace_Next > 10 Then Replace_Next = 1 ' replace them in turn 1..10, then loop back to 1
        Product_Position(Replace_Next) = .... ' put initial position here
    Else
        Product_Counter = Product_Counter + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well - I want to make sure we continue keeping track of the other bottles.  So if bottle 1 reaches the end we should still watch the other bottles to see where they are.

Comment: Think of it this way:  We have a conveyor that can only fit 10 bottles.  I need to track the position of each of the 10 bottles.  Once bottle 11 comes on - That means bottle 1 is completed and off the conveyor.  So, bottle 11 becomes bottle 1, so I need to reset the position of bottle1 to 0, and continue tracking bottles 2-9 while also tracking bottle 11(Not bottle 1).  Once bottle 12 comes on it becomes bottle 2, and I need to reset the position of bottle 2 to '0' and continue tracking all bottles.

Comment: So the new bottle just replaces bottle1?  In which case leave Product_Counter at 10, and just change Product_Position(1)

Comment: Right - That's the part i'm confused about.  It's not just replacing position(1), it's also replacing all other positions, when the next bottle leaves the conveyor - 1, leaves first, then 2, then 3, etc.  It's just a constant rotation once there are 10 bottles on the conveyor. Any help there?

Comment: You'll need a separate variable to store which bottle is to be replaced, I think.  I've updated what I wrote

Comment: So the process is place bottle, whose status is incomplete, on the conveyor at inch 0. Move the conveyor  along inch by inch using the pulse button. When the bottle reaches position 1 which is x number of inches along the belt, perform a function on it. Move the conveyor along and inch etc. When the bottle has passes inch number 128, the bottle's status in now complete and it is taken off the conveyor. So now you need  a bottle structure with status and position and unique ID,  a list of incomplete bottles and a list of bottles on the conveyor.= and a list of complete bottles

Comment: Add the bottle from the list of incomplete bottles to the list of bottles on the conveyor and remove it from the list when it is completed and move it to a list of completed bottles.

Comment: @DavidWilson That's exactly it.  I'm struggling to figure out how I can best do that.  For some reason I can't programmatically accomplish this.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse - I think you're just as close as I was - But Neither of us are quite there.  I don't quite understand what you are suggesting here: Product_Position(Replace_Next) = ....  Are you able to move this to a chat?

Comment: I don't see how to - it may require 1k rep

Answer (score 2):

Your conveyor is FIFO (first-in, first-out), so rather than constantly shifting, reindexing and/or rebuilding (=reset?) an array to make it ***seem like it is FIFO***, Net includes the `Queue(Of T)` collection ***which is FIFO***.

A `LinkedList(Of T)` could also be used.  A plain `List(Of T)` would also work, but if the add/remove frequency is high, that will result in the same inefficient shifting taking place under the hood that you have with an array.

The only issue is enforcement of the size limit, which is easily handled with a small class wrapper.  I assume there is something interesting or identifiable about the bottles other than their position.  The test code uses a sequence ID and the contents.

```
Friend Class Bottle
    Public Property Contents As String
    Public Property SequenceID As Int32
    ' etc
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0}:  ({1})", SequenceID.ToString("00"), Contents)
    End Function
End Class
```

You likely have more relevant information to show.  The, the collection class:

```
Friend Class BottleQueue
    Private mcol As Queue(Of Bottle)
    Private lbls As Label()
    Private MaxSize As Int32 = 10     ' default

    Public Sub New(size As Int32)
        MaxSize = size

        mcol = New Queue(Of Bottle)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(size As Int32, l As Label())
        Me.New(size)
        lbls = l
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(b As Bottle)
        mcol.Enqueue(b)

        Do Until mcol.Count <= MaxSize
            mcol.Dequeue()
        Loop
        UpdateDisplay()
    End Sub

    Public Function Peek() As Bottle
        Return mcol.ElementAtOrDefault(0)
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property Count() As Int32
        Get
            Return mcol.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function Remove() As Bottle
        Dim b As Bottle = Nothing

        If mcol.Count > 0 Then
            b = mcol.Dequeue
            UpdateDisplay()
        End If

        Return b
    End Function

    Private Sub UpdateDisplay()
        Dim n As Int32

        If lbls Is Nothing OrElse lbls.Count = 0 Then
            Return
        End If

        For n = 0 To mcol.Count - 1
            lbls(n).Text = mcol.ElementAtOrDefault(n).ToString
        Next

        For n = n To lbls.Count - 1
            lbls(n).Text = "(empty)"
        Next
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property GetQueue As Bottle()
        Get
            Return mcol.ToArray()
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

The class has 2 display means built in.  One updates a set of labels.  Since it is a collection, it also provides a way to get the current collection in order for a collection type control such as a `Listbox`.  An even better way would be if the collection itself was "observable", so it could be used as a datasource.

It also provides a way to `Remove`the next bottle manually.  Removing from a specific index (e.g. `Remove(3)`) is antithetical to a `Queue`, so it isnt implemented.

test code:

```
' form level vars:
Private BottleQ As BottleQueue
Private BottleID As Int32 = 7

' form load, passing the labels to use
' using a queue size of FIVE for test
BottleQ = New BottleQueue(5, New Label() {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5})
```

Adding an item:

```
Dim material = {"Napalm", "Beer", "Perfume", "Pepsi", "Cyanide", "Wine"}

' add new bottle with something in it
BottleQ.Add(New Bottle With {.Contents = material(RNG.Next(0, material.Count)), 
             .SequenceID = BottleID})
BottleID += 1

' clear and show the contents in a listbox:
lbQueView.Items.Clear()
lbQueView.Items.AddRange(BottleQ.GetQueue)
```

The `BottleId` arbitrarily starts at 7, the contents are random.  BTW, `material` shows just about the only way I ever use an array: when the contents are fixed and known ahead of time.  In almost all other cases, a NET collection of one sort or another, is probably a better choice.

Because it is not an observable collection (and that is a little at odds with the FIFO nature), the listbox needs to be cleared each time.  That could be internal to the class like the label display is.  Results:

[image]

On the right, the first 5 are shown in order; 3 clicks later, the result is on the left:  everything moved up 3 and 3 new items have been added.

Note: If the code using this needs to know when/which `Bottle` is removed from the conveyor, the class could include a `ItemRemoved` event which provides the item/Bottle just removed when adding forces one out.  That is probably the case, but the question doesnt mention it.

Comment: This was a fantastic and thorough answer.  I much appreciate it.